# How does std::sort handle NaN values?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std, rcpparmadillo

I was using the `sort` function in the Armadillo library but it kept firing "NaN errors" which were nonexistent when I checked manually. I've switched to the `std::sort` function and it worked!

So I'm wondering: how does the `std::sort` function treat NaNs?

Comment: Comparisons in the standard library work on the basis of a "strict weak ordering" enforced by `operator<`.

Comment: The way that `sort()` works is documented, though there are variants as free function and as memberfunction. Which one do you mean? What questions do you have that isn't answered in e.g. cppreference.com? Also, what code were you using for either framework? Be sure to supply a [mcve] for each. Also, what were your observations that lead you to the conclusion it had anything to do with NaNs? As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does C++ STL sort check for NaN?

`std::sort` uses the comparison function that you provide for it. If your function "checks for NaN", then so does `std::sort` does so through the comparison function. If you don't provide a comparison function, then `std::less` is used by default. That uses the operator `<`. The behaviour of `<` with NaNs does not satisfy the requirements of `std::sort` and the behaviour will be undefined if you try to sort a range that contains NaN (unless you provide a custom comparison function).

Comment: more than one NaN? Given than `NaN < x` and `NaN > x` both return false I think sorting any number of NaNs is undefined?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the algorithm never uses `>`, so it doesn't matter how it behaves as far as `std::sort` is concerned.

Comment: OK `NaN < x` and `x < NaN` both return false

Comment: ...from which you can deduce that the two are equivalent, because neither is less than the other. That's simply how the predicates for many STL algos work. You need a custom comparator.

Comment: @AlanBirtles On the other hand, there is always another value that also returns false for both: `x` itself. But I suppose that it is a problem for NaN to be equal to all other values. I've edited the anwer.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue the result of `<` implies that `NaN` is equal to all other values which it isn't

Comment: @AlanBirtles well, by definition it **is** equal to all other values when compared with `<`. But being equal to more than one other value is presumably the problem. That is, the values that are equal to NaN are not equal to each other.

Comment: Some additional detail: The requirements are listed in [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). The violated requirement is the last bullet: *if `equiv(a, b) == true` and `equiv(b, c) == true`, then `equiv(a, c) == true`.*